# providing granular data for data intensive web service

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am developing a webservice that is really data intensive.
Unfortunately all of the data returned by it is not needed for all the calls, but might be needed for another call.

An overly simplified response might look something like below:

```
Response : {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D : {
        X : {

        }
        y,
        z
    }
}
```

I want to provide flexibility to callers such that they can request for specific data from the big object.
I thought of achieving it by exposing enums, and taking list of enum as input. Each enum map to a field in response.

example if caller needs only A and D, then they can specify it by passing list of enums like ImmutableList.of(GET_ENUM_A, GET_ENUM_D)
And at web service end I can compute only A and D.

questions:
Is there better way of taking input (other than enum) of what data is needed by caller?

I would like to give control to user over more fine grained data, eg. they can specify what part of D is needed.
GET_ENUM_D_X.

At server end, I am thinking of implementing it using command pattern, having a command for each enum and executing it only if the corresponding enum is present in the list.

- Here my D will be a facade.
- If granular data is requested then don't use facade instead use command for X.

Issue I can think of:

- I end up with too many commands.
- If a command is a subset of another command and both are requested the execute only superset command (we need to do this in code)

Is there a better way of solving this problem.

(PS : I am not interested in fragmenting it to smaller APIs, because of certain use cases).

Comment: The problem with enums is that if you add a field W to your D object, then you need to add an enum to reflect that. Why not letting the client choose what to read? i.e. he might use a POJO that contains only A and D.X fields to deserialize the received JSON.

Comment: To clarify, it is not a REST webservice, both input and output are strongly typed.

Comment: Since I can go any depth, Root->D->X->..., I though of having it implemented using composite pattern as well, but I wanted to implement a generic solution for it which I can extend easily to other APIs as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jackson to serialize your objects you can take advantage of views:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews

Basically, you define a view class and then when serializing the object you would pass in the view you want. For example:

```
// View definitions:
class Views {
        static interface A { }
        static interface B { }
        static interface C { }
        static class AC implements A, C { }
}

public class Bean {

        @JsonView(Views.A.class) 
        public Object getA() {
          // compute A
        }
        @JsonView(Views.B.class) 
        public Object getB() {
          // compute B
        }
        @JsonView(Views.C.class) 
        public Object getC() {
          // compute C
        }
}
```

Then, when you want to serialize you can pass in the view you want:

```
objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, beanInstance, A.class);
```

If you want to get both a and c you would use the AC class

```
objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, beanInstance, AC.class);
```

Comment: I don't want to do extra processing as well, the motive is not only to reduce the bytes transferred over wire but also not to do un-necessary computation as well.

Comment: You can put these annotations on getters as well as fields

Comment: It is not really a REST webservice, but I am still open to your suggestions as I can internally implement similar concept.
But I am still not able to figure out, how it is going to fit into a bigger picture.